# gloda query result infinite loop?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am querying Thunderbird/Gloda on starred messages (happens for other queries as well). Also, I am assuming that all returned messages should have an id (not return: undefined for id).

```
  let query = Gloda.newQuery(Gloda.NOUN_MESSAGE);query.bodyMatches("dd");
```

or ....

```
let query = Gloda.newQuery(Gloda.NOUN_MESSAGE);query.starred(true);
```

I have one starred message. If I iterate over the returned collection, I get 1 id (by alert(msg.id);) and millions of 'undefined'. I actually have to kill Thunderbird then to get out of an apparent infinite loop.

Observations:
aCollection.items.length=0   (but there is 1 id)

ways to iterate, all lead to the unending loop:

1)
`for each (let glodaMsg in aCollection)`

2)

```
for each (let [, glodaMsg] in Iterator(aCollection))
```

3)   this is from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Gloda_examples

```
try {
        for (var glodaMsg in aCollection) {
            //do something with the Conversation here
            alert(glodaMsg.id);
        }
    } catch (e) {};
```

just an additional remark:
if I try to display the collection in a tabmail, it is empty, corresponding to length==0:

using for display:

```
        let tabmail = document.getElementById("tabmail");
          tabmail.openTab("glodaList", {
            collection: aCollection,
            title: "glodasearch",
            background: false
          });
```

what is happening, what am I doing wrong?

any help is appreciated,

Klaus

Answer (score 0):

I tried with true in quotes and tested it on my console. `query.starred("true");` should do the trick.